# Let $f:[1,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ , $a_n=f(n)$. Prove if $lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ then $lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, functions

> Let $f:[1,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ , $a_n=f(n)$. Prove if  $lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ then $lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$
>
> and I need to prove that the other way is wrong ( $lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$ $\implies $$lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$)

---

My attempt:

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }(a_n)=L\: \iff $$$$\forall \:Ɛ>0,\exists N\in \mathbb{N},\forall n>N,|a_n-L|<\:Ɛ$$

and we know : $$lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=L \iff|f(n)-L|<Ɛ $$

and  $$a_n=f(n)$$

so the statement is true .

---

Is this correct? and to prove the different way is false I need to find example to prove it false any idea how can I find example ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You've sort of missed the point of the first part: the point is that $x \to \infty$ means that for all *real* $x$ larger than some $N$ you have $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$. (Usually $N$ itself is also understood as real, though of course it can be assumed natural. But $x$ must be understood as real in this context.) You can just find an appropriate integer $N$ for this definition and show that it will work for the sequence definition.

Now the point is that going the other way, knowing about $f(n)$ tells you nothing about, say, $f(n+1/2)$. So you could have a function with $f(n)$ converging and $f(n+1/2)$ not converging. Or you could have a function where $f(n+a)$ converges for each $a \in [0,1)$ but to different limits.

If you're still confused it might help to draw some pictures.

Answer (score 2):

We claim that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L.$

Fix $\varepsilon>0.$
By assumption, there exists a natural number $N$ such that for any real number $x\geq N,$ we have 
$$|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon.$$
Fix a natural number $n\geq N.$
Since natural number is also a real number, therefore
$$|a_n-L| = |f(n)-L|<\varepsilon.$$
Hence, we have proven that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L.$$

To prove the converse is false, consider $f(x)=\sin(x\pi).$
Note that $f(n) = \sin(n\pi) = 0$ for all natural number $n.$
This implies that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}f(n) = 0.$$
But 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$$
does not exist as $f$ keep oscillating between $-1$ and $1.$